# Can transverse axis of a hyperbola be a function of $\theta$

Tags: conic-sections

A hyperbola, having the transverse axis of length 2 sin $\theta $
, is confocal with the ellipse $3x^2 + y^2 =12$
then, its equation is ?

My question is about the transverse axis as a function of $\theta$. The transverse axis of a hyperbola is a constant, so how it is given here as 2 sin$\theta$? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me $\theta$ is just a parameter here — nothing to do with polar coordinates. As it varies, the shape/eccentricity of the hyperbola varies.